# Rails as_json overwrite in model with parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I'm trying to add the point's name, which is a virtual attribute, to my json requests.

The problem is that I need the language_id of the user to get the correct name in the database.

I can't find any snippet allowing to call a method with a parameter in a "as_json overwrite".

This my current code :

```
# Adds the name of the point when query is json
def as_json(options={})
  super.as_json(options).merge({:name => name(language_id)})
end 

# Returns the name of the point regarding the column in use in this project.
def name(language_id)
  @name ||= get_point_name(language_id)
end
```

I get either :

- wrong number of arguments (0 for 1), if I remove the parameter
- undefined local variable or method `column_id' for #, if I leave the parameter

What is working, is when I replace language_id by the value it is supposed to be (i.e the integer 80). In this way, I get my point's name in the correct language...

I've also tried to call a the global method current_language that I usually use in my controllers/views, but it seems I can't call such a global method from the model :-(

Thx for helping

Answer (score 2):

I think you should go with a custom serializer if you are doing lots of this stuff, see [ActiveModel::Serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers).

However, you could include the method that returns the correct name in the #as_json override.

```
super({:methods => [:name]}.merge(options))
```